# Can i add Aspect J jar into a Maven project through pom.xml?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

i was wondering whether i can add Aspect J to a Maven project because there doesn't seem to be a public repository for it to be added to pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectjrt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectjweaver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where version is 1.5.3 and dependent on which one you wish to use.